# Accentuate range of line in plot - only closed interval

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to accentuate a closed range in a ggplot line plot. Here is an example:

```
df = data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
  y = c(1,2,1,2,1,3,4,3,4,3),
  se = 0.1,
  cond = c(F,T,T,F,F,F,F,T,T,F),
  g = c('M','M','M','M','M','F','F','F','F','F')
)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, alpha = cond, color = g, group = g)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-2*se, ymax=y+2*se), width=.01) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(`TRUE` = 1, `FALSE` = .3))
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: First version of plot]

I would like only the region between the data points with cond == T to be highlighted, not the line element afterwards.

If I try the following, the highlighting is correct, but the different parts of the lines are not properly connected anymore:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, alpha = cond, color = g)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-2*se, ymax=y+2*se), width=.01) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(`TRUE` = 1, `FALSE` = .3))
```

[image: Second version of the plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new variable that is `TRUE` only when the the value for `cond`
and following value
are `TRUE`. We can use `dplyr::lead()` for this. Then instead of using `cond` for
the alpha argument we use the newly created `between_cond` in the `ggplot::geom_line()`
call.

```r
df <- 
  df |> 
  mutate(between_cond = cond & lead(cond))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, alpha = cond, color = g, group = g)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-2*se, ymax=y+2*se), width=.01) +
  geom_line(aes(alpha = between_cond)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(`TRUE` = 1, `FALSE` = .3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solves my question. Would you know why the same doesn't work for size? `ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color = g, group = g, size = cond))` and 
`geom_line(aes(size = between_cond))` and `scale_size_manual(values = c(\`TRUE\` = 3, \`FALSE\` = 1))` wrongly sizes the line element afterwards?

Comment: Apparently size is deprecated for lines, and it works if I use linewidth instead. Thanks!